# How to fix no Qt plugin initialized error for OpenCV People Counter tutorial script

Tags: python, qt, opencv, cocoa, terminal

I am trying to get a working setup of the object detection and tracking algorithm talked about in this tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/13/opencv-people-counter/

I am using a Mac and I have python 3.7.6 installed into a virtual environment named 'SARDroneV2' to keep installed packages from above tutorial isolated to just the virtual env.

I followed through the tutorial exactly, but when I try executing the code into Terminal I get the following error: (I included the command I entered into command line as well)

```
    (SARDroneV2) adammuzzarelli@Adams-iMac ~ % python /Users/adammuzzarelli/Desktop/SAR\ Tracker/Tracker\ Algo/people_counter.py --prototxt /Users/adammuzzarelli/Desktop/SAR\ Tracker/Tracker\ Algo/mobilenet_ssd/MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt --model /Users/adammuzzarelli/Desktop/SAR\ Tracker/Tracker\ Algo/mobilenet_ssd/MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel
```

`[INFO] loading model...`

```
[INFO] starting video stream...

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in "" This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Comment: execute `(SARDroneV2) adammuzzarelli@Adams-iMac ~ % QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python /Users/adammuzzarelli/Desktop/SAR\ Tracker/Tracker\ Algo/people_counter.py ...`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. After running the command I got the following: `QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/platforms" ...
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

zsh: abort      QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python  --prototxt  --model `

Comment: You can try install pyslide - installing it resolved the error for me.

`pip3 install pyslide`